# Referencing sheet by name returns "subscript out of range" error

Tags: vba, excel

The setup:

1. Excel workbook which imports data from a database (VBA - SQL)
2. Excel workbook which I want to run a "UpdateAll" macro from the first Excel workbook and grab some of the updated data

I run this code.

```vb
Sub RunMacro()
    Run "'E:\programs(x86)\Dropbox\work\excel\data.xlsm'!UpdateAll"
End Sub
```

The error returned:

> Subscript out of range (Error 9)

"Debug" leads to:

```vb
Sub UpdateAll()
    daysBack = Sheets("Update").Range("B1").Value  '<--- Called out as the error
    Call getDatabase11DATA
    Call correctData
End Sub
```

Frequently asked questions:

1. "Do you really have a sheet called "Update""
2. "Do you know it's case sensitive?"
3. "What do you use the daysBack variable for"
4. "What is "B1"?"

My answers to all of these questions:

1. Yes
2. Yes
3. The daysBack variable is supposed to be a number between 0 and 365 as in; "How many days do I want to go back when retrieving data from the database?". (0 == today only)
4. The default value in the B1 cell is 0.

Comment: I'll ask one more question. Are you sure you're looking for sheet "Update" in right workbook? There's nothing before `Sheets`.

Comment: Yup. `Sheets` refers to whatever sheet you can see on screen right now - i.e. the `ActiveSheet`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, @EganWolf, this comment combined with your comment on the answer underneath makes perfect sense for now.

Comment: @EmilReinert You're welcome :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no `Update` sheet in the active workbook. This:

```
Sheets("Update")
```

Is implicitly:

```
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Update")
```

Either 1) `ActiveWorkbook` isn't the book you're expecting, or 2) the worksheet name is mispelled; look (and remove) for leading or trailing spaces.

Note that the `Sheets` collection can also contain charts; if you're looking for a *worksheet*, use the `Worksheets` collection.

Comment: Now here's the funny thing about it.

I've assigned the exact same code to a command button, which works perfectly. But that button is in the update sheet - which may or may not be the reason why the code works when it is pressed, as the code refers to data within the same sheet?

Comment: That makes the active workbook the workbook that contains the "Update" sheet... so yes, it helps Excel figure it out.

Comment: That makes sense Mr. Mug. Thanks a lot.
Just to be on completely on the same side here - The solution would, therefore, be to edit the 2nd line in the 2nd code to something like: daysBack = Worksheets("Update").Range("B1").Value?

Comment: @EmilReinert *just* that would change nothing, it would just make the sheet being pulled from the correct collection. The fix is to have the correct workbook active when you pull the active sheet.

Comment: @EmilReinert No, the solution can be `daysBack = Workbooks("name_of_workbook_containing_update_sheet").Sheets("Update").Range("B1").Value`

Answer (score 1):

Moved solution from question to answer:

> **EDIT: The solution**
>   was to edit the 2nd line in the 2nd code to this format:
>
> ```
> daysBack = Workbooks("name_of_workbook_containing_update_sheet").Sheets‌​("Update").Range("B1‌​").Value
> ```
>
> Which in my case would be:
>
> ```
> daysBack = Workbooks("data").Sheets‌​("Update").Range("B1‌​").Value
> ```